# Android webservice asp .asmx

Tags: java, android, android-service, ksoap2

I try to connect Android - webservice by ksoap2. I have a problem. When I run in Java a Console application, it runs ok. But when I copy this code to Android it gives an error:

> "Java.Net.UnknowHostException.jeryservice.somee.com".

My code:

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://jeryservice.somee.com/";
String URL = "http://jeryservice.somee.com/myservice/Service1.asmx";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://jeryservice.somee.com/test";
SoapObject request= null;
String rs="";
request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"test");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet=true;
request.addProperty("name", " Jery ok man");
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE transp=null;
transp=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try {
  transp.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
  Object rsl=envelope.getResponse();
  rs=rsl.toString();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ok-> "+ rs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  catch(Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error->"+ ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: you get this error because jeryservice.somee.com can not detected. you have to check internet connection in device/emulator first

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```